# Releasing MediaPlayer in a multi-Activity application

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm designing a game which has multiple `Activities` and a `MediaPlayer` that plays music through the whole application. Now my question is simple: when do I release the `MediaPlayer`? I can't put the call in any `Activity`'s `onDestroy()` since it will kill the `MediaPlayer` for all other `Activities`. Any workaround? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When do you want to release the MediaPlayer? Assuming you want to release it on application exit, and your media player runs in a Service, I don't see any problem to release it in onDestroy() on the activity that started the service.

Comment: @AndyRes, Yes, I want it to be released on application termination, but MediaPlayer isn't running in a Service.

Comment: Hm... If you need the MediaPlayer to play music in background through the whole application, across multiple activities, putting the MP in a service would be the proper way to do it. The main activity will start your service, and also it will shut down. Just an idea...